# How to write to an other terminal with a running program in it in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, subprocess, stdin, minecraft, gnome-terminal

I am currently making a program in python to open minecraft servers. I've already done a window where you can choose a server in a list and launch it or make a backup. When you launch it, a new terminal open (with `os.system('gnome-terminal...')`) and the java program starts. Is there a way to send some text (like commands) to this java program from the first terminal ?

[Here is my code](https://pastebin.com/NmNiJYRD)

I've tried many things with subprocess but without a satisfying result.

**EDIT**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import gtk
import re
import os
import time

active_button = 0

servers = [["Server 1","/home/myname/Desktop/server1","server.jar"],
            ["Serveur 2","/home/myname/Desktop/server2","server.jar"]]

def button_selection(button, num):
    global active_button
    state=button.state
    if state >= 1:
        active_button = int(num)

def validation(widget):
    path = servers[active_button][1]
    server = servers[active_button][2]
    command = """gnome-terminal --working-directory="%s" -e 'java -jar %s'""" % (path, server)
    print(command)
    os.system(command)

def save(widget):
    path = servers[active_button][1]
    server = servers[active_button][2]
    print "cp -a '%s' /home/myname/Documents/backups_minecraft_servers/%s" % (path+"/world", time.strftime("%d_%m_%Y-%T"))
    os.system("cp -a '%s' /home/myname/Documents/backups_minecraft_servers/%s" % (path+"/world", time.strftime("%d_%m_%Y-%T")))
    print("Backup finished")

def main():
    window = gtk.Window()
    vbox = gtk.VBox()
    hbox = gtk.HBox()

    validate = gtk.Button("Validate")
    validate.connect("clicked", validation)

    backup = gtk.Button("Backup")
    backup.connect("clicked", save)

    hbox.pack_start(validate)
    hbox.pack_start(vbox)
    hbox.pack_start(backup)

    buttons = [gtk.RadioButton(None, servers[0][0])]
    vbox.pack_start(buttons[0])

    for server in servers[1:]:
        buttons.append(gtk.RadioButton(buttons[0], server[0]))
        vbox.pack_start(buttons[-1])

    for i in range(len(buttons)):
        buttons[i].connect("toggled", button_selection, i)


    window.add(hbox)
    window.show_all()
    gtk.main()

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Can you post your code here? Easier to read and debug\

Comment: One options perhaps not the best is to setup the server process so that it has its stdin connected to a fifo. Then you can send it commands by writing to the fifo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, don't ever use `os.system`. Always use the `subprocess` module for launching new processes, as it handles many of the edge cases much better. `subprocess.check_call` can do everything `os.system` can do, and much more, and it checks for errors, something `os.system` doesn't do.

Secondly, don't use `gnome-terminal` to create an interactive terminal to run your subprocess in! Create a pseudoterminal (pty) instead; that way your program can maintain control over the behavior of the child. Underneath the hood, that's how a program like `gnome-terminal` works itself: it creates a pty for the shell and the programs launched by the shell to run in, and then it reads from the pty and renders the results graphically.

Your program can create a pty for each child program you want to run, and then your program can communicate with the child program exactly like how `gnome-terminal` can. You can do this with the `pty` module in the Python standard library, but you might want to consider using the `pexpect` package instead as it simplifies the process substantially.

If you don't need a full terminal, you can do this even more simply by just opening a pipe to the child process. The `subprocess` module in the standard library provides the `Popen` class which can be used to do this.

In your specific case I would recommend `pexpect`. It's easy to use and will "do the right thing" for this kind of job.